# Rails has_scope gem used on nil param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, has-scope

In my app I'm using has_scope gem. I have made some scope they are working to find a string in a field.
But now I would add a new scope to find all records where a specific param is nil
How to do that ?
I'm unable to find the right syntax, now I have that in model :

```
student.rb

scope :connected, -> connected { where([:last_connected_at].nil?)}


student_controller.rb

class EtudiantsController < ApplicationController

  has_scope :connected


  def index          
    @students = apply_scopes(Student).all
  end


 end

application.html.erb

<%= link_to "Student never connected", "/etudiants?connected=false"  %><br />
```

But it doesn't working ...

Could you help me ?

Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

In your student_controller.rb write:

```
has_scope :connected, type: :boolean
```

And in your application.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "Student never connected", "/etudiants?connected=true"  %><br />
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
 scope :connected, -> connected { where([:last_connected_at].present?)}
```

Or

```
 scope :connected, -> connected { where([:last_connected_at].try?)}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but it's not better :-(. present? say nothing and try? say : "undefined method `try?' for [:last_connected_at]:Array"